# Не выводит переменную float

Tags: java, float, scanner

Есть простенькое задание согласно которому, надо заставить пользователя ввести число с запятой, а потом вывести это число на экран.
Я написал такой код

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tochka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("введи число");
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ваше число - " + num.nextFloat ());
    }
}
```

В результате получил вот такую ошибку:

```
введи число
2.3

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:947)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2505)
    at tochka.main(tochka.java:7)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

При этом если поменять значение `nextFloat` на `nextInt` программа работает правильно.
Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так?

Comment: может нужно с запятой число вводить?

Comment: А если попробовать ввести `2,3`, может в локали разделитель запятая прописан? Странно, но вдруг.

Comment: Почему нет кода, который заставляет пользователя вводить запятую? Если исправить ошибку ввода, то это не поможет решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Да с запятой все сработало!
Я не понимаю как это работает.
Т.е. как правильно вводить числа через запятую или точку? Я знаю что в "обычной" жизни вводится через запятую, но тут он даже в ответе выдает через точку:
введи число
2,2
Ваше число - 2.2

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Ну да, вот пишут дело в локали. Как она в яве устроена я не знаю, дальше сами разбирайтесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332312/8324991

Comment: Спасибо всем отписавшимся. У меня есть еще один вопрос по сайту. Я так понял тут есть что то вроде репутации, я могу как то поощрить тех кто пытался мне помочь?

Comment: Поощрить можно, только если дан ответ отдельным постом - принять ответ как верный, также можно поставить плюсик. Комментарии не влияют на репутацию. Можно попросить автора полезного комментария оформить его как ответ, если он захочет.

Comment: @Soskok За комментарии - никак. Если же будет оформлен полноценный ответ - тогда да, ответ можно плюсануть.

Comment: О, так и знал, что наверняка дубликат. Плюсаните дубликат кто может.